# dnsmasq for siriproxy on ubuntu

Tags: iphone

I am running ubuntu 10.04 with dnsmasq 2.52

For running siriproxy I have added

```
address=/guzzoni.apple.com/(mylaptopip) to dnsmasq.conf at /etc/dnsmasq.conf
```

But when I ping ping guzzoni.apple.com it doesnt connect any clues??

```
PING reg3.guzzoni-apple.com.akadns.net (17.174.4.14) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- reg3.guzzoni-apple.com.akadns.net ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 7023ms
```

P.S. I have issued `sudo killall named` and `sudo killalll dnsmasq` and restarted `dnsmasq` successfully.

Comment: `guzzoni.apple.com` is timing out for me too (when I do a ping from my Macintosh command line); looks like you might either have the wrong server name, or it's resolving to the wrong IP, or you're just doing the wrong thing, period.

Comment: I got it working. So once you issue the dnsmasq on the server you have to change the dns on the client or iphone to use the server's ip :). I just got it working and felt like a kid getting a toy :) Thank god siri is a machine and not a person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. So once you issue the dnsmasq on the server you have to change the dns on the client or iphone to use the server's ip :). I just got it working and felt like a kid getting a toy :) Thank god siri is a machine and not a person.